# Allocation methodologies under FRTBA SA

Tags: banking-regulations, market-risk, allocation

Hi I have been comparing several methodologies for allocation of standalone capital charge to the underlying desks and I keep getting very vague results on which allocation is superior in terms of minim volatility in changes of DOD charges, and raw risk associated with the move. Has anyone went through similar exercises recently and has some methodologies or findings that could be helpful

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is, but perhaps [this Moody Euler marginal back-allocation](https://www.moodysanalytics.com/-/media/whitepaper/2017/frtb-marginal-back-allocation.pdf) can help.